# Why is there a difference in the same material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Used same nodes with 2.79 and 2.82. Huge difference. I can't see color in 2.79. Doing the same thing in 2.82, the color and shaders are seen/visible. Why?

[image]

Comment: Is it cycles-2.79 vs Cycles-2.82, that has to be compared or solved OR cycles-2.79 vs EEVEE-2.82?

Comment: I guess it's just the hdri

Answer (score 3):

There are no shaders in this material.

Don't know how 2.8x functions, but for 2.79 put an *Emission* shader between every *RGB* node input.